# How to take integral of a second order partial derivative of a function?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative

My textbook shows that for a function $u(x,y)$ satisfies $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}= 0$, we can integrate this relation twice and get $u(x,y) = F(x) + G(y)$, which makes me confused.

I think integrating $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}= 0$ will lead to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= C_1(y)$ because when integrating $x$, $y$ could be seen as a constant, and continue integrating it we will get $u(x,y)=C_2(y)+C$ where $\frac{dC_2(y)}{dy} =C_1(y)$. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I think you mean $\require{color}\dfrac{\partial^{\color{red}2} u}{\partial x\partial y}$ rather than $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x\partial y}$.  When you integrate your $C$ depends on the other variable ($\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)=C_1(y)$ so integrating $u(x,y)=u(x,y_0)+\int_{y_0}^y C_1(\eta)\,\mathrm{d}\eta$.

Comment: Yes，thanks for your correction and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that something is wrong with your solution from symmetry: $x$ and $y$ should be interchangable. Your solution doesn't reflect that.
When you integrate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = C_1(y)$ you left out the $x$-dependency of $C$:

$$
u(x,y) = \int \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(y) \text{d} y + C(x)
$$